# How to generate a signature for OAuth

Tags: php, rest, oauth

I'm currently attempting to generate a signature to make API calls to quickbooks online, however I keep getting authentication errors. I'm sure the signature portion is where I'm going wrong. Is this incorrect:

```
//method to generate signature
//$this->method = "GET"
//QBO_SANDBOX_URL = 'https://some_url.com/'
//$this->_query = 'something=something'

  public function generate_signature()
{

    $base = $this->_method.'&'.rawurlencode($this->_url.QBO_SANDBOX_URL.'v3/company/'.$this->_realm_id).'&'
        .rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=".rawurlencode($this->_consumer_key).'&'
        .'&oauth_nonce='.rawurlencode('34604g54654y456546')
        .'&oauth_signature_method='.rawurlencode('HMAC-SHA1')
        .'&oauth_timestamp='.rawurlencode(time())
        .'&oauth_token='.rawurlencode($this->_auth_token)
        .'&oauth_version='.rawurlencode('1.0')
        .'&'.rawurlencode($this->_query));

    $key = rawurlencode($this->_consumer_secret.'&'.$this->_token_secret);

    $this->_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base, $key, true));

}
```

Now when I go to send my request, here are the headers:

```
$this->_headers = array(
        'Authorization: '.urlencode('OAuth oauth_token="'.$this->_auth_token.'",oauth_nonce="ea9ec8429b68d6b77cd5600adbbb0456",oauth_consumer_key="'.$this->_consumer_key.'",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="'.time().'", oauth_version ="1.0"oauth_signature="'.$this->_signature.'"').''

    );
```

I get a 401 Authorization response. Am I signing incorrectly?

EDIT: All fields not included here (i.e `$this->_auth_token`) are set.

Comment: I am trying to do this same thing and I am trying to use this code, how are you getting the App Token Secret? According to the [documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000500_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app), I need to have the signature to retrieve the App Token Secret, but you are using it to generate the signature `$this->_token_secret`, any help?

Comment: @Josh Whitlow: Your app token should be given to you by whomever services you are trying to authenticate against. Usually in a dashboard somewhere.  By the way the above code works, the issue was the double `&` that ends the second line of the `$base` variable declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that might use this as a basis for their own integration, there is one other issue with the code originally posted:

```
$key = rawurlencode($this->_consumer_secret.'&'.$this->_token_secret);
```

should be

```
$key = rawurlencode($this->_consumer_secret).'&'.rawurlencode($this->_token_secret);
```

Comment: Fixing the question might be better.

Comment: @Whitecat did that as well - without the key being correct the generated signature would never be correct.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was in the base string:

```
.rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=".rawurlencode($this->_consumer_key).'&'
    .'&oauth_nonce='.rawurlencode('34604g54654y456546')
```

The `&` after the consumer key and once again before the oauth_nonce.

Answer (score 0):

In the signature creation I think it lacks the call to `rawurlencode()`:

```
$this->_signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base, $key, true)));
```

instead :

```
$this->_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base, $key, true));
```